# Standard basis for complex polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a standard basis for complex polynomials?

Similar to how their is a standard basis for real poylnomials like $P_2(R)$ $->$ {1,x,x^2}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If you view $\mathbb{C}[x]$ (polynomials in $x$ with complex coefficients) as a complex vector space $\beta = \{1,x,x^2,\dots\}$ is the standard basis.

If you view $\mathbb{C}[x]$ as a real vector space, you could use the basis $\beta = \{1,i,x,ix,x^2,ix^2,\dots\}$.