# Infinite basis concerning the polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, hamel-basis

I read an answer in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992343) that $\{1,x,x^2,\cdots\}$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{C}[x]$. I want to extend it a bit more general:

> Is it true that if $p_0,p_1,\dots$ are any polynomials from $\mathbb{C}[x]$, then $\{p_0,p_1,\dots\}$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{C}[x]$ as well, or does it also require that $\deg p_n=n$?

Comment: The first claim is not true, as you can take all $p_i$ to be the zero polynomial. Requiring $\deg p_n = n$ gives a sufficient condition, although it is obviously not necessary.

Comment: As an example: $\{x^2+1,x^2+x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,x^6,\dots\}$ is also a basis for $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Comment: No basis can contain a linearly dependent set, and there are lots of linearly dependent sets of polynomials. So even though there are lots of bases, one has to be a little careful at least.

Comment: @WhatsUp By "sufficient condition" you mean that if $\deg p_n=n$, then $\{p_0,p_1,\dots\}$ forms a basis for $C[x]$? and "... it is obviously not necessary" the converse direction does not hold?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. The above comment of @MichaelBurr gives an example that the converse direction does not hold.

Comment: OK. It makes much sense now. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

No, arbitrary countable subset of polynomials does not necessarily form a basis. If each degree of $p_n = n$, it is true that it's a basis.